# Nullpointerexception while checking an array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, 2d

I am pretty new to java but i have to initialize an 2d-array size n, in this example 10.
After initialization i want to check the diagonal entries if they are false, and if set them to true. After i want to return value of i.

This is what i coded:

First of all initialization of the array:

```
public static void init(int n) {
        boolean friendship[][] = new boolean[n][n];}
```

and after i tried this:

```
public static int addUser(String name) {
        int id=0;
        for ( int i=0;i<friendship.length;i++) {
            if ( friendship[i][i] = false) {
                friendship[i][i] = true;
                id = i;
            }
        }
        return id;
    }
```

Sadly its throwing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at x.SocialNetwork.addUser(SocialNetwork.java:18)
    at x.SocialNetwork.main(SocialNetwork.java:53)
```

What can i do to fix this?

PS: Sorry for bad english and formatting.

Comment: Why are you bothering to check if they're false?  Why not just set them to true regardless?  (by the way, use == instead of = to compare things)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a `static` field called `friendship`. In this method

```
public static void init(int n) {
     boolean friendship[][] = new boolean[n][n];
}
```

you are declaring a new local `friendship` variable, that is [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) the `static` member. Therefore, the `static` `friendship` field remains `null` and when you try to access it in `addUser` you get a `NullPointerException`.

Use

```
public static void init(int n) {
     friendship = new boolean[n][n];
}
```

assuming again that you have something like

```
public static boolean[][] friendship;
```

---

In  this

```
if ( friendship[i][i] = false) {
```

you are actually setting `friendship[i][i]` to `false`. The equality operator is `==`.

---

This is how I see your class

```
public class Test {
    /* visibility identifier doesn't matter */ static boolean[][] friendship;

    public static void init(int n) {
        // this is a different variable from the member declared above
        // it is a local variable
        boolean friendship[][] = new boolean[n][n]; 
    }

    public static int addUser(String username) {
        int id=0;
        for ( int i=0;i<friendship.length;i++) {
            if ( friendship[i][i] = false) { // referring to static field, not the local variable in init()
                friendship[i][i] = true;
                id = i;
            }
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't have a static field, and what is a static init? Is it a static initializer? Why this static needed here?

Comment: @nikpon Using `static` here is just a design choice. It's not the real issue. The issue is OP has two variables that have the same name, one `static` and one local. The local one is shadowing the `static` one.

Comment: Where did you see the design here? You are absolutely incorrect about static.

Comment: @nikpon You could get rid of the `static` and OP would have the same problem assuming that they have an instance field called `friendship`.

Comment: Nope, this absolutely not necessary, the same problem is not the issue, and you have nothing to improve the OP problem

Comment: @nikpon I am assuming OP is calling their `init` method before calling their `addUser` method. In this case, the field `friendship` is not initialized, because another local variable of the same name is initialized instead. That's why OP is getting `NullPointerException`. I'm explaining why OP is getting NPE, I'm not trying to improve their design.

Comment: Where did you see that? What ave you trying to argue is you answer didn't solve OP's problem correctly.

Comment: @nikpon OP states `First of all initialization of the array:` before their `init` method, thinking that in that method, their `friendship` array will be initialized. But the `addUser` method is using a different `friendship` array, one that hasn't been initialized. My answer shows how to fix that.

Comment: OP initializes the array in the init method, and this is what proposed to the post why on earth would he want to use a different array? You have only written erroneous code and nothing more.

Comment: @nikpon The array initialized in `init()` is local. It is a new declaration. Because it is local, it cannot be used in `addUser`. Therefore, we must assume that there is another variable called `friendship` declared in a visible scope. This is known as [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).

Comment: If it's local why it has a public access, or it international then it should be probably public. Only one variable in the code should be used to initialize the array.

Comment: @nikpon `Only one variable in the code should be used to initialize the array.` I agree with you. The problem in OP's code is that they are initializing a **different** variable. Visibility modifiers are irrelevant to this specific case. See my edit.

Comment: Nope, ofcourse it's relevant, and what you call "visibility" is known as access. In your edit you did copy/paste bad code and plagiarize the content. Nothing more.

Comment: @nikpon In the edit, which I assume is what OP has, if you change `boolean friendship[][] = new boolean[n][n];` to `friendship = new boolean[n][n]` in the `init(int)` method, the OP will no longer get a `NullPointerException`, again assuming that `init` is called before any `addUser()`.

Comment: It's not true, until the method init is called NPE is obvious. I your code you *never* did it. What do you think OP is used is not true.

Comment: @nikpon We assume `init` is called from some client code, not internally. Even if `init` was called, OP's code would _still_ cause NPE. My solution fixes that, assuming still, that the client code is calling `init()` first. I don't know how much more clear I can be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41358/discussion-between-sotirios-delimanolis-and-nikpon)

Comment: You are, not am I, it's not shown in the code, and it's a error if it didnt regardles of the local variable, init is init and it should be called appropriately. If not not program Java.

Comment: Do you agree that if OP did call `init` they would still get `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I'm not agree with the if, there's no if in the OP.

Comment: @nikpon You are allowed to make assumptions. Especially when OP states `After initialization i want to check...`

Comment: I can make assumptions but my point is the method init should be called in the code, or proved by the statement of the evidence, without it my assumptions is opposite and my point is to show the error.

Comment: @nikpon My point is that **regardless** of if the `init()` method is called first, _OP's code_ **will** throw a `NullPointerException`. That is because `init()` is not initializing the same variable as the one used in `addUser()`. Please read the link on shadowing that I linked earlier.

Comment: In that way you just ignore my point. Your point you could express without copying erroneous code. This way they are writing bad code looking on answers like yours.

Comment: @nikpon Your solution completely changes OP's design and, although that may be a good thing, it doesn't explain why OP was experiencing a `NullPointerException`. In my answer, I'm not trying to explain how to write good code, I'm just stating what the cause of the `NullPointerException` is.

Comment: @nikpon OP asked `What can i do to fix this?`, not `what is good design?` Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for that. A better place would be `codereview.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: I've already told you if you are calling that *design* then I should be Emperor of China if that true. In the code not only one error, you stuck on the NPE and ignore any other errors including my point. Bad of yours.

Comment: Also you didn't explain how the *shadowing* could help to solve OP's problem.

Comment: @nikpon No, **shadowing is the cause of the problem**.

Comment: Neither of them is explained.

Comment: @nikpon My answer states `you are declaring a new local friendship variable, that is shadowing the static member.` How is that not explained?

Comment: It was like something not important, just mentioned about and doesn't point. Also if you place references in comments are useless, edit the post and add details.

Comment: @nikpon What else do you want me to say about it? I can link the JLS if you want, but I doubt OP would read it, it's quite a large document.

Comment: I think it is my fault. I downvoted `nikpon` because of his rudeness, and maybe he thought it was you. I think he is a "revenge voter" (I got a "serial downvoting" shortly after having an issue with him myself). +1 compensation, anyway.

Comment: @SJuan76 Ah, thanks, but don't downvote on rudeness. Flag for rudeness, but their answer has some merit too.